# C# comparing two object if they are equal

Tags: c#

```
if(setting.ConvertedValue.Equals(m_MatchingModules[i].Group[j]))
{
}
```

I am working on a project and I need to check the code above if the values are equal. I never enter the `if` statement. My `ConvertedValue` variable is of type `Object` while `Group` is a list of `Int`s. I saw in the debugger that both values are equal 3 but the `.Equals` does not find them equal.

Comment: _"Convertedvalue is of type Object "_ what kind of object? Maybe one like this: `"3"`?

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. We don't have enough information to help you at the moment.

Comment: ConvertedValue is of type object and has a value  3 (int not string).

Comment: Is m_MatchingModules[i].Group[j] also of type int?

Comment: Yes m_MatchingModules[i].Group[j] also of type int is of type int.

Comment: You are probably not comparing what you think you are.  If ConvertedValue is of type Object with value set to 3, using .Equals will return True if compared to an int with value set to 3.

Comment: If possible, you should consider to use the IEqualitComparer<T> for your specific types. Here is the interface plus an example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Test test = obj as Test;
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return Value == test.Value &&
        String1 == test.String1 &&
        String2 == test.String2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using == instead. Equals is for checking object equality and can return false if the type is different even if the value is the same for value types.

```
someInt.Equals(someLong); // false

someInt == someLong; // true
```

Comment: I don't think so - in a quick test ´someInt.Equals(someLong)` also returns ´true.´

Comment: that's funny - doing the same with short parameter names (i and j) give different results (https://dotnetfiddle.net/QsrdBW)

Comment: Might be because long to int requires an explicit conversion as it is 8 byte to 4 byte whereas short to int (2 to 4) doesn't.

Comment: T̶h̶a̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶s̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶r̶s̶e̶ ̶-̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶m̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶i̶f̶f̶e̶r̶e̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶i̶f̶f̶e̶r̶e̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶m̶a̶i̶n̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶.̶ ̶S̶e̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶e̶n̶g̶t̶h̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶e̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶m̶a̶t̶t̶e̶r̶s̶.̶.̶.̶ - ok, seems you were right, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ValueType.Equals method.

```
if(ValueType.Equals(setting.ConvertedValue,m_MatchingModules[i].Group[j]))
```